# Get user profile on login with AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to get the user profile data on login with AJAX and PHP, without reloading the page. Here is my login.php code. All I have to is if the login is successful than I want to alert the user's name and email.

```php
<?php    
  include 'connection.php';    

  $login_mobile = $_POST['login_mobile'];
  $login_password = $_POST['login_password'];

  $check = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from sign_up_users where Mobile = '$login_mobile' and Password = '$login_password'");
  if (mysqli_num_rows($check) > 0)
  {
    $_SESSION['login_mobile'] = $login_mobile;
    echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>200));
  }
  else
  {
    echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>201));
  }     
  mysqli_close($connection); `    
?>
```

```js
function make_login() {
  var login_mobile = $('#login_mobile').val();
  var login_password = $('#login_password').val();
  if (login_mobile != "" && login_password != "") {
    $.ajax({
      url: "php/login.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        login_mobile: login_mobile,
        login_password: login_password
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(dataResult) {
        var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
        if (dataResult.statusCode == 200) {
          // if success than i want to store name and email in var of login user
          alert("hurray!!!!");
        } else if (dataResult.statusCode == 201) {
          alert('invalid login');
        }
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert('Please fill all the field !');
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any error?

Comment: It's clear from your example you already understand how to return JSON in PHP, and access the properties of the deserialised object in the resulting AJAX call in JS. Therefore I'm not sure where the issue is; just add the properties of the user's data from your mySQL query to the response and access them in JS.

Comment: *However* one very important point to note is that your login is not secure in the slightest. You're wide open to SQL injection attack. You need to fix that ASAP.

Comment: Also a 201 response is for 'Created', not for a failed login. Return a 401 for an unauthorised response, or return 200 with a boolean flag to indicate state.

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for SQL injection attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that.

Comment: _**Never ever** ever never_ store passwords in plain text! You should _always_ hash the passwords using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and only store the hashes. Then you can use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your php code

```
<?php    
  include 'connection.php';    

  $login_mobile = $_POST['login_mobile'];
  $login_password = $_POST['login_password'];

  $check = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from sign_up_users where Mobile = '$login_mobile' and Password = '$login_password'");
  if (mysqli_num_rows($check) > 0)
  {
    $_SESSION['login_mobile'] = $login_mobile;

    // you can just add name or email detail in return array to ajax request

    echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>200,'name'=>$check['name'],'email'=>$check['email'])); 
  }
  else
  {
    echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>201));
  }     
  mysqli_close($connection); `    
?>
```

**Here is you ajax jquery code**

```
 function make_login() {
  var login_mobile = $('#login_mobile').val();
  var login_password = $('#login_password').val();
  if (login_mobile != "" && login_password != "") {
    $.ajax({
      url: "php/login.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        login_mobile: login_mobile,
        login_password: login_password
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(dataResult) {
        var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
        if (dataResult.statusCode == 200) {
          // if success than i want to store name and email in var of login user

          // You can access name and email like below

             var name = dataResult.name;
             var email = dataResult.email;

          alert(
                 "name="+name+"<br/>"+"email = "+email
               );
        } else if (dataResult.statusCode == 201) {
          alert('invalid login');
        }
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert('Please fill all the field !');
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer need explanition ! Can you explain please what did you change ?

Comment: Actually he is not returning data of name and email in php code than how could he get information of name and email . I just return name and email detail in php code & than access it on jquery code after statusCode ==200.

Comment: I meant put explanition in your answer, NVM